# Sample settings.xml required

Tags: eclipse, maven-2

Can somebody provide me link to a sample `settings.xml`?
My problem is that I have eclipse maven plugin. This eclipse is one which I have copied from somewhere and the plugin came with it.
Now the `settings.xml` isn't created as usual in `.m2` folder. So I need a sample `settings.xml` so that the maven plugin works in my eclipse.

NB: I am using eclipse Galileo 3.5

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [m2eclipse FAQ](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/m2eclipse-faq.html):

> #### How to Configure Proxy and location of Maven local repository
>
> Eclipse Plugin is using Maven’s `settings.xml` for proxy, local repository location and any other environment-specific configuration. This way we can use same settings between the command line and the IDE.
>
> Default location of the `settings.xml` is at **`<user home>/.m2/settings.xml`**, but you can also specify location of the global settings, i.e. one in **`<maven home>/conf/settings.xml`**.

You can see what a minimal settings.xml looks like in this blog post on "[**Build a mixed Scala 2.8/Java application from scratch with Maven (Eclipse Settings)**](http://web.archive.org/web/20120721015358/http://mackaz.de/111)":

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>
    C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/.m2/repository
  </localRepository>
  <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
  <usePluginRegistry>false</usePluginRegistry>
  <offline>false</offline>
</settings>
```

(Change the '`localRepository`' path to adapt it to your encvironment)

All the details on a maven **`settings.xml`** are in the [**Maven Setting reference** page](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did as you mentioned. But now the eclipse console shows the following error: Unable to update index for Central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2. Can u tell me how to fix this?

Comment: @Anand: it can be a proxy issue (http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Unable-to-update-index-for-central-td139784.html) or a bug in your current m2eclipse version (https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-2284?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel): the version 0.12.0 should work.